# Adding array element to JSON column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, update, postgresql-9.4, json

We have a table (`avl_vehiculo_data_estatica`), which has a JSON column (`data_vehdatesta`) and, we need to update the contents of it by adding an element to actual JSON array that's stored in it:

Actual contents:

```
[{"iddata":"1","valor":"18"},{"iddata":"2","valor":"10"},{"iddata":"3","valor":"N/A"},{"iddata":"4","valor":"53"},{"iddata":"5","valor":"Agencia Vespucio Oeste"}]
```

Desired contents:

```
[{"iddata":"1","valor":"18"},{"iddata":"2","valor":"10"},{"iddata":"3","valor":"N/A"},{"iddata":"4","valor":"53"},{"iddata":"5","valor":"Agencia Vespucio Oeste"}, {"iddata":"6","valor":"ACTIVO"}]
```

So, what has to be done is to add a new JSON array element with the following values:

```
{"iddata":"6","valor":"ACTIVO"}
```

We've tried several PostgreSQL JSON related operators and functions, but haven't been able to find the correct mix to achieve such update, so any suggestions might be helpful.

DB Version:

```
PostgreSQL 9.4.9 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit
```

PS: There's a similar [question/answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102906/adding-elements-into-postgresql-json-array-field) but no exactly the same as our case.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `||` to concatenate `jsonb`, if you're using 9.5+.

```
SELECT lhs::jsonb || rhs::jsonb
FROM ( VALUES 
  (
    '[{"iddata":"1","valor":"18"},{"iddata":"2","valor":"10"},{"iddata":"3","valor":"N/A"},{"iddata":"4","valor":"53"},{"iddata":"5","valor":"Agencia Vespucio Oeste"}]',
    '{"iddata":"6","valor":"ACTIVO"}'
  )
) AS t(lhs,rhs);
```

Outputs:

```
[{"valor": "18", "iddata": "1"}, {"valor": "10", "iddata": "2"}, {"valor": "N/A", "iddata": "3"}, {"valor": "53", "iddata": "4"}, {"valor": "Agencia Vespucio Oeste", "iddata": "5"}, {"valor": "ACTIVO", "iddata": "6"}]
```

*Note the explicit cast should **not** be required. I suggest storing your types as `JSONB` to start out with, unless you have good reason not to.*

Comment: close, buy not the exact solution, as the array brackets are in the way. I tried `select data_vehdatesta || '{"iddata":"6","valor":"ACTIVO"}' from avl_vehiculo_data_estatica` but could it be due to the fact that I'm using 9.4.9 and not 9.5+?

Comment: @GonzaloVasquez I don't think `jsonb || jsonb` is in 9.4 can you check to see if you're getting the output that i'm getting above. I pasted my output.

Comment: mmmmm: `ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb || jsonb` ... not supported

Comment: @GonzaloVasquez sounds like the other answer then is an exact duplicate. You need something like plv8 that pulls out the json in text, appends the json, and returns a new json.