# How to read jsonb or json in postgresql spi?

Tags: postgresql, json, c

*How can I read a json/jsonb field in a PostgreSQL server side function?*

I am trying to write a server side function using C and SPI for PostgreSQL 11. The json field in mind is simple and contain only unnested key (`text`) and value (`float8`) pairs. I'd like to read these key value pairs into my C code and process it.

But after much searching on Google and here at DB.SE, I can't find any documentation on this. The results I got are for using json/jsonb on the client side, e.g.:

[Pushing or appending to JSON array in PostgreSQL 9.4](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102906)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32458524

I see there is `PG_GETARG_JSONB`, e.g. [here](https://gist.github.com/ArtemGr/67196668a1ea22cfda66). But it is buried beneath other things and seems to require [an external library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/libglim/).

Any pointers are appreciated.